# How to pass Many2one field from purchase order line to account move line

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I tried to get the same field from purchase_order_line to account_move_line

```
class PurchaseLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order.line'

task_id = fields.Many2one('project.task', string='Rubriques', store=True)
```

And i tried to override the method *_prepare_account_move_line*

```
class AccountMoveLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.move.line"

task_id = fields.Many2one('project.task', string='Rubriques', store=True)

def _prepare_account_move_line(self, move):
    res = super(AccountMoveLine, self)._prepare_account_move_line(move)
    res.update({
        'task_id': self.order_id.task_id.id
    })
    return res
```

but that doesn't work do u have idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your extension to `_prepare_account_move_line` has to be made on model `purchase.order.line` and you have a little mistake in it:

```py
class PurchaseLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = "purchase.order.line"

    def _prepare_account_move_line(self, move):
        res = super(AccountMoveLine, self)._prepare_account_move_line(move)
        res.update({
            "task_id": self.task_id.id
        })
        return res
```

The little mistake was `self.order_id.task_id.id` which should be `self.task_id.id` because you've defined `task_id` directly on the purchase line where this method is called.

Comment: doesnt work sadly, i got the field but not the value in it :(

Comment: I means thats work but i could like to get the same value, i should say it in my post :/

Comment: If you don't get the same value, then it obvisiouly does not work ;-)

Comment: Right now i don't the mistake in my solution :-/

Comment: what do you mean by didnt get the same value, are you referring that the in invoice line the field is not shown and value is not getting stored ?

Comment: @Sidharth Panda
Yeah! In my purchase order line i selected "04 task" ( for exemple ) and in my account move line nothing, a empty field and i would like to got the same task

Comment: IN account.move.line if you are adding a field then you also have to add that same field to journal entries line as well 
what i mean to say is in account.move.line you have ```invoice_line_ids``` and ```line_ids``` so you have to add the same field in both, after that you can store or do whatever you want in that field